# Entity Framework: check if object exists and check if it has an associated object

Tags: entity-framework, entity, exists, associated-object

In a many-to-many relationship between File and Category I want to check if a file exists and if so, if it has any categories (because there's a chance it may not have any) :

```
        public bool existsInDBAndHasCategories(string path)
    {
        using (WinFileContextContainer c = new WinFileContextContainer())
        {
            return c.File.Any((o => o.path == path));
        }
    }
```

This checks if a file with this path has a record in the database. I got this from a thread on this site. Truth be told I am still not good with LINQ and lambdas, so I don't know how to extend it to give me BOOLEAN for any categories as well. Thanks in advance for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add another condition to your method (Assuming you have defined `Categories` as a list of `Category` in `File` class) :

```
return c.File.Any((o => o.path == path && o.Categories.Any()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not familiar with Lamba, start learning simple LinQ, before you move on to lambda inside Linq queries.

You code shoud be like this:

```
public bool existsInDBAndHasCategories(string path)
{
    using (WinFileContextContainer c = new WinFileContextContainer())
    {
        var query = from f in c.File
            where f.Path == path &&
            (f.Categories != null || f.Categories.Count != 0)
            select f;
        return (f.Count != 0)
    }
}
```